# google map not chancing its location on dragging

Tags: iphone, objective-c

hi i have text field when i enter location name on text field then google map directed me to that location , but if i draq google map with mouse in iphone then it not change its location and also when i double tapp on map then also map not zooming the location  this is the method in which i calling the another function and sending the locationcoordinates

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation{
    NSLog(@"location found... updating region");
    [self addPins:location2d.latitude  lon:location2d.longitude];
}
```

Comment: is your map view not scrolling?

Comment: yes mapview not scrolling

Comment: write this code in your viewDidLoad [self.view bringSubviewToFront:mapView];

Comment: no effect on map it still not changing location

Comment: check if any other view is above your mapview

Answer (score 0):

Check that userInteraction on your MKMapView is enabled and att code here how you are adding that MKMapView to your view controller.